# how to manage magento multi site in local and in live server

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, e-commerce

I am still new to magento. I have successfully installed magento ce on my local wamp server. I choose magento because I heard that it has multi site feature. My client have three separate website that are running on three domain name(www.sample1.com, www.sample2.com, www.sample3.com). I am planning to control them on one admin.

I would like to know how can I manage to create multi site on my local and how can I upload it on live server.

Also, can someone explain to me in simple the architecture of multi site of magento. If I'm not mistaken, I understood it this way.

**admin** -> my backend maybe running soon www.sample1.com that handles all my website.

**website** -> This is where I will give separate domain. for example website one is running on www.sample1.com. website two is running on www.sample2.com. and finally website three is running on www.sample3.com

**store** -> I don't have clear understanding of it.

**store view** -> this is the presentation layer. the most fron-end of the website where products, themes are displayed.

This is kind of stupid but i'm still new to magento.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the following: http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/how-to-set-up-multiple-store-fronts-with-magento/ https://docs.nexcess.net/article/multiple-storefronts-with-magento.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the link helped however this only works in the live server. How do I set up my local wamp server to handle multiple site? thanks

Comment: You need to add virtual hosts and edit your hosts file to allow you to have them: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts

Comment: Thanks, I create my own virtual host and it worked.